# Как найти слово в Html файле в java?

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование

получаю через класс document из библиотеки jsoup html документ,как реализовать в нем поиск слов?

Comment: использовать Substring()?

Comment: @tym32167 поиск осуществляется не из строки, а из html документа

Comment: Который является строкой по сути

Answer (score 1):

```
Document myDocument = ...; // как-то получили экземпляр Документа.
Element body = myDocument.body(); // собственно элементы тела Документа. (есть ещё заголовок - для него есть метод .head().

Elements allElementsOfBody = body.getAllElements();

List<String> allTextContentLines = allElementsOfBody.eachText();

// далее ищем интересную подстроку в каждой строке allTextContentLines.
```

см. https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html

https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html